# Core data objects should automatically be sorted at midnight

Tags: ios, core-data, nsdate

I am creating a To-Do list app for iOS. The To-Do items list is divided into sections:

Section 0 -> OVERDUE items

Section 1 -> TODAY items

Section 2 -> TOMORROW items

Section 3 -> UPCOMING items

Section 4 -> SOMEDAY items

Section 5 -> COMPLETED items

As you may imagine, after midnight, the remaining TODAY items should pass to the OVERDUE section, the TOMORROW items should pass to the TODAY section and some of the UPCOMING items should pass to the TOMORROW section.

The app as it is now and if the user launches the app in the morning, all items are shown in their respective section.

The problem occurs when the user is working with the app just before midnight and  just pass midnight. The items do not automatically pass to the correct section.

I can test the app only on the simulator, but I guess the issue will also happen on a real device.

All items have an attribute called todoDueDate, and all of them have the same time part of the date value, all items time is set at 10:00am.

To distribute the items into the sections I am using a transient attribute, called sectionIdentifier, which is defined in a NSManagedObject subclass named ToDoItem.

Here you have the method:

```
-(NSString *)sectionIdentifier{

    [self willAccessValueForKey:@"sectionIdentifier"];
    NSString *tmp = [self primitiveValueForKey:@"sectionIdentifier"];
    [self didAccessValueForKey:@"sectionIdentifier"];




    if (!tmp){


        NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
        NSInteger comps = (NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit);

        NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
        NSDate *date = self.todoDueDate;

        NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
        [components setCalendar:calendar];
        [components setYear:2065];
        [components setMonth:11];
        [components setDay:12];

        NSDate *dateFuturoSomeday = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];

        NSCalendar *calendar1 = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
        NSDateComponents *components1 = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
        [components1 setCalendar:calendar1];
        [components1 setYear:2065];
        [components1 setMonth:11];
        [components1 setDay:13];

        NSDate *dateFuturoCompleted = [calendar1 dateFromComponents:components1];




        NSDateComponents *date1Components = [calendar components:comps
                                                        fromDate: today];
        NSDateComponents *date2Components = [calendar components:comps
                                                        fromDate: date];
        NSDateComponents *date3Components = [calendar components:comps
                                                        fromDate: dateFuturoSomeday];
        NSDateComponents *date4Components = [calendar components:comps
                                                        fromDate: dateFuturoCompleted];


        today = [calendar dateFromComponents:date1Components];
        date = [calendar dateFromComponents:date2Components];
        dateFuturoSomeday = [calendar dateFromComponents:date3Components];
        dateFuturoCompleted = [calendar dateFromComponents:date4Components];



        NSInteger daysAfterToday = [calendar components:NSDayCalendarUnit
                                               fromDate:today toDate:date options:0].day;
       // NSString *section;
        if (daysAfterToday < 0) {
            tmp  = @"0";
        } else if (daysAfterToday == 0) {
            tmp = @"1";
        } else if (daysAfterToday > 0 && daysAfterToday < 2) {
            tmp = @"2";
        }
        else if ([self.todoDueDate isEqualToDate:dateFuturoSomeday]){
            tmp = @"4";
        }
        else if ([self.todoDueDate isEqualToDate:dateFuturoCompleted]){
            tmp = @"5";
        }
        else {
            tmp = @"3";
        }






        [self setPrimitiveValue:tmp forKey:@"sectionIdentifier"];

    }


    return tmp;

}
```

What could I do to achieve the desired behaviour? That means, when the user is working with the app at midnight, the items should pass automatically to the expected section.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout [UILocalNotification](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

While designed for ... well, *local notifications*, you can easily use the notification firing as a method to refresh the sorting on your fetched data.

Suggestions:

- applicationDidBecomeActive - schedule a UILocaleNotification for midnight that night (optionally set it to repeat daily ... just in case someone leaves it open for >24 hours!)
- applicationDidEnterBackground - nullify the notification
- For handling the notification, [this post](http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/07/29/iphone-programming-tutorial-local-notifications/) (while old) has a decent overview of how to setup a UILocationNotification and handle it's firing from the app delegate. In your case, just force the sorting to update.

Comment: Thank you @greymouser, I will try doing it that way. But do I need to take care about Time Zones?

Comment: @mvasco I would assume almost certainly. Just decide now whether to store local times in your Core Data store, or always store sanitized time (e.g. UTC). Transform the values when getting or setting them, or even set the attribute type to Transformable with an NSValueTransformer that converts to and from current local time to UTC.

Comment: I would appreciate your advice on this matter. You have seen how do I sort the items into the sections in the above method. And I also told you that all items have the same time part on their date values (10:00 am). I have seen that all date values are from type 2014-02-17 17:00:00 +0000. I am talking regarding the iOS simulator, if I put 10:00am, the stored value is 17:00. Should I change the way I am storing the date values?

Comment: Sounds like you're in US MNT time? /me check your profile ... yup, Mexico. :-) Personally, when serializing or storing in databases (or things like Core Data), I prefer transforming the date into UTC -- your 17:00 above (v. 10:00). Now, when you read the data out, with Core Data, you have two choices -- "localify" the time in your getter, and "utc-ify" in your setter, or use a Transformable type and an NSValueTranformer that does the same thing. In this case, where you are likely to use NSPredicates to search dates, I'd stick with an NSDate type and using the getter/setter method. 1/2

Comment: 2/2 ... Transformable types are less searchable -- easy for equality, less so for concepts like greater than or less than. You probably need to transform the date less than you think (and then I initially thought of) ... really you just need to change the display of the date (via an NSDateFormatter) when you display it. But you may need an internal helper to transform dates when searching. The nice part is that if you store in GMT/UTC (NSDate's default), then the app will "just work" if the user happens to cross time zones.

Comment: Thank you for your time and nice explanation. That all means that I am storing dates  in GMT/UTC, and taking into account my above mentioned method, am I sorting the items also in GMT/UTC?

Comment: Yup! Sorting them in native-NSDate GMT, but formatting them for display for your locale with NSDateFormatter.

Comment: That means that internally, i am always working with GMT/UTC, but displaying the data in local time? Then, what happens if I fire the notification at local midnight? When does an item with due date from tomorrow pass to the TODAY section? Sorry, but I don't have this matter clear enough. All items have 10:00 UTM time.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47707/discussion-between-mvasco-and-greymouser)